# ADF migrate app with 11.1.1.6 to 11.1.2.0

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

a question about migration of applications based on adf version 11.1.1.6 to version 11.1.2.0

app: core java jsf / adf components

whether there is a possibility to occur, there are any conflicts.

oracle writes http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/index-091111.html
If exist the ability to migrate to 11.1.1.9 with no problem.

Anyone have any experience related

You will require modifications to the application code?
You will be required to update the script builder app?
and it looks like a case of the configuration of WebLogic Server with an increase version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning an upgrade go directly to the latest version 12.2.1 and not to the outdated 11.1.2.*.
See the support matrix:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/122-cert-2708091.html#MigrationSupport

In general the main difference is that the JSF engine switched from JSF 1 to 2 - when you open the application in the new JDeveloper it will migrate your project for you.